# In what sense can the Universe be thought of as a true isolated system?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, universe

I've seen the question asked before, but I didn't find the way it was asked or the answers to be satisfactory. I must admit I am no expert, so I hope for answers suited more for the layman, but as long as it isn't extremely technical it should be fine.

My understanding of the second law of thermodynamics is that isolated systems are purely hypothetical, and that they are created when you construct hypothetical barriers around a proposed system, such as a hot pan and a cold steak isolated from the energy and matter of the rest of the Universe. Of course, the steak and skillet could never exist in reality without the rest of the Universe to contain them, which is why it's purely hypothetical.

I'm not at all convinced that we can consider the pan and steak to be a true analogy for the Universe. The pan and steak are isolated from the Universe, but from what is the Universe itself isolated? By definition, it can't be isolated from anything. Maybe I'm sneaking in the common definition of "isolated" instead of the thermodynamic one here, but I don't think it makes a difference.

In short, I'm convinced that the idea of a system in isolation from energy and matter is a concept that loses any useful meaning when we're talking about the Universe itself, and not about the sorts of hypothetical systems the law is intended to describe. If I am wrong, I am very interested to know why.

Comment: If you don’t think that the universe is an isolated system, then what other system do you think it is interacting with?

Comment: Well, the definition of the Universe obviously seems to preclude that possibility. I'm just not convinced that's a good enough reason to say we can think of it as isolated in terms of the second law without any shred of doubt, and I'm surprised by how many scientists do so without question. It seems rather presumptuous, given how little we actually know about the Universe, to say that the whole thing behaves the same way as a part of it that is only hypothetically isolated from the rest. Put another way: how do we know an isolated Universe behaves the same as an isolated part of a Universe?

Comment: *Maybe I'm sneaking in the common definition of "isolated" instead of the thermodynamic one here, but I don't think it makes a difference.*  If it didn't make a difference you wouldn't have this confusion.  The lesson here is to not change parts of the definition and expect the results to be the same.

Comment: But I can still take the original definition and have the same problem. The second law was invented to describe a part of the Universe is in isolation from the rest of the Universe, and that is a purely hypothetical scenario. I don't see how we can say the same rule applies if we're leaving the realm of hypothetical systems and instead talking about the real Universe, which is still mostly mysterious to us. I'll grant that it **could** be true that heat death is inevitable, I just don't understand where the 100% certainty of some comes from.